# What will be the terminal case of maxconnect4 game?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, minimax

I understand tic-tac-toe using minimax algorithm where terminal cases are win, lost and draw  - 10,0,-10.

program termninates when some one wins, loose or draw. As connect four game do not have three terminal states, rather than a scoreboard after the game is finished, How do I determine its terminal cases from evaluation function? How to implement the evaluation function?

```
int minimax(char board[3][3], int depth, bool isMax)
{
int score = evaluate(board);

// If Maximizer has won the game return his/her
// evaluated score
if (score == 10)
    return score;

// If Minimizer has won the game return his/her
// evaluated score
if (score == -10)
    return score;

// If there are no more moves and no winner then
// it is a tie
if (isMovesLeft(board)==false)
    return 0;

// If this maximizer's move
if (isMax)
{
    int best = -1000;

    // Traverse all cells
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
        {
            // Check if cell is empty
            if (board[i][j]=='_')
            {
                // Make the move
                board[i][j] = player;

                // Call minimax recursively and choose
                // the maximum value
                best = max( best,
                    minimax(board, depth+1, !isMax) );

                // Undo the move
                board[i][j] = '_';
            }
        }
    }
    return best;
}

// If this minimizer's move
else
{
    int best = 1000;

    // Traverse all cells
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
        {
            // Check if cell is empty
            if (board[i][j]=='_')
            {
                // Make the move
                board[i][j] = opponent;

                // Call minimax recursively and choose
                // the minimum value
                best = min(best,
                       minimax(board, depth+1, !isMax));

                // Undo the move
                board[i][j] = '_';
            }
        }
    }
    return best;
   }
}
```

But for connect4, how do I calculate evaluation function and how it will define terminal cases (except when the board is full)?

Comment: With the assumption that you can't traverse the search-space completely (as with most games), it's the task of you evaluation function to somehow approximate this score. So the score-values, when stopping at some depth is 1,0,-1 in end-states and something between [1,-1] if not (solely calculated by your function).

Answer (score 0):

> As connect four game do not have three terminal states, rather than a scoreboard after the game is finished,

First of all, your are wrong in saying connect four doesn't have three terminal stages. It too can only end in either win, lose, or draw.

The problem is that connect four is sufficiently complex that it is impossible to evaluate the tree until those terminal stages are reached. That is why in games more complicated than the most basic (like tic tac toe), a predetermined search depth is given for the search, and all nodes at the end of that depth are viewed as terminal. This depthy is usually determined by time constraints in an iterative deepening framework.

Since in reality these nodes are not terminal, we can no longer evaluate them using 0, 1, and -1. Instead, we expand our range, treating wins as an arbitrarily high number, loses as arbitrarily low, and using a heuristic evaluation function to determine in between values. One possible heuristic is number of three in a rows a player has. For more complex connect four heuristics, read Victor Aliss's thesis on the topic.